# How to secure work flow in Azure Logic App

Tags: azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

I'm able to create work flow which can create repository in Azure DevOps with HTTP action in Logic App. Actually i have provided base64 encrypted PAT in Header section of HTTP action, this is not secure right. I have tried to store PAT in Key Vault & tried with get secret option in Logic App, but seems something wrong. Can anyone please share the steps how to call PAT from Key vault to Logic App Http action.

FYI:
[image]

Comment: May I know if you have resolved your issue by below solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to retrieve the secrets from key vault in logic app in the following way-

1. Primarily, I created a key vault and changed the  access configuration as below

[image]

2. Added PAT, as a secret in it.

[image]

3. Enabled managed identity in my logic app.

[image]

4. Created access policy in the key vault which will give access to the logic app as below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

5. Once the access policy created, I added the actions in my logic app workflow as below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Enable **Secure Outputs** in the **Settings** in order to encrypt the PAT value in output or else PAT value will get populated in the output.

[image]

After enabling above, you will get the output like below

[image]

Then I added HTTP action to fetch all the repositories and used PAT value from dynamic content.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**References:**

[Interacting with Key Vault from Logic Apps securely – 365 by Thijs](https://365bythijs.be/2021/11/16/interacting-with-key-vault-from-logic-apps-securely/).

Comment: Hi @Ikhtesam Afrin,

Comment: Hi @VardhanReddy, is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done using RBAC (access control) instead of using Access Policies

giving the logic app identity the "Key Vault Secrets User" role should be enough, but havent tried myself

Comment: Thanks for the valuable info. Is there any way to restrict users & allow specific users to Logic App/Work Flow. Please suggest best apprach.

Comment: yes MS recently released new roles for logic app standard

please see this link

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-integration-services-blog/announcement-azure-logic-apps-standard-rbac-roles-in-public/ba-p/3906600